# Call javascript from html object or iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-object

I have the following problem using HTML and javascript.
My website has, in a div, an HTML page included like this:

```
<object name="cont" type="text/html" data="myHtmlPage.html"></object>
```

I have a javascript function (linked to the main page) that changes the content of that object.

The code works well, because I can navigate in the "inner" page without changing the outside context.

The problem is that now I need to call, from an html page loaded in that object,   a function on the main page javascript (needs to be called on the main page one because I have to change some properties of the main page divs)

Is there a way to do that?

I hope I was clear, thank you for your help.

Matteo

**Edit:**

I have an index.html that has a series of sections (is a single page website).

In a section (#services) I have two divs: one where you can select a service and one where there is an iFrame(#content)  (previously html object).

In a js (serviceMenuHandler.js) there is this function:

```
function changeService(servizio){
            var pathServizio;
            var pathMenu;
            pathServizio = servizio + ".html";
            pathBg = 'url(img/'+servizio+'.jpg)';
            if(servizio=="applicazioni" || servizio == "progettazione"){
                pathServizio = "errore.html";
            }
            document.getElementById('content').src=pathServizio;
            $("#services").css('background',pathBg);}`
}
```

I have another page, let's call it serivice1.html, that is loaded via that function in the iFrame, correctly working.

From that page I need to call the changeService function on the parent page, so I can change service and background.

As suggested by JSantosh, I have a javascript function in service1.html that calls the method `parent.changeService(service)` but that doesn't do any action.

I normally load the js via `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/serviceMenuHandler.js"></script>` on the top of the body, so before the iFrame.

Hoping that now is more clear,
thank you

**Edit 2**:

with Firefox it works easily calling the function on parent as suggested in the comments.

Does somebody know why it isn't working on Chrome?

Comment: Why are you using an `<object>` instead of an `<iframe>` (which would give you effectively the same thing, just with better support and a better defined set of APIs)?

Comment: Because I'm not very expert in this field and it looked like the better solution.
Anyway it wouldn't be a problem for me to change it in a iframe if there is a way to do what I want to do from an iframe!

Comment: try calling `parent.functionName()` from  `myHtmlPage.html`

Comment: @JSantosh doesn't work

Comment: it works for me .  just load the JS function that you want to call before `iframe` or `object` in DOM and try . @Matteo

Comment: I did this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/serviceMenuHandler.js"></script>` before the object. Than in a js function in the included page I did this: `parent.changeService(...);` but nothing happens. Where am I wrong? (serviceMenuHandler is the js where the function changeService is)

Comment: @JSantosh I forgot to tag you in last comment, do you know where am I wrong?

Comment: can you provide your full code, so that me or someone can see whats happening and what you are doing . part of code is insufficient to fix you issue .

Comment: @JSantosh I edited the post, thanks

Comment: The function you're trying to call from the object/iframe in the parent window has to be a global object aka attached to `window`. Then you should be able to do something like `window.top.myFunction()`

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
 window.changeServiceFromFrame = function(service){
   changeService(service)
  };
</script> ` in the index and `window.top.changeServiceFromFrame(service);` called in the iframe page javascript is not working. Is not even working if i do a no parameters function and i put in it a simple alert. @StephenKorecky

Comment: I found out that wasn't working on my local copy on chrome, but it is working on firefox and even on chrome using the website uploaded to my host. Thank you guys!

Comment: May be you should use `$("#content").ready(function(){your_code_here});`?

Answer (score 0):

ok i think i know what you are trying to do.

you want to call the function changeservice on a page other than the index.

the easiest way to do this would be to move the function into a .js file then include then file on both pages that would give access to the functions on the .js file to any page with the include. the include would look like this.

```
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

i hope this helps.

Comment: i recommend putting this include in the <head></head>